# How can I read the file contents using http synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webclient, dotnet-httpclient, synchronous

In an event that is called synchronously, so I can't use await (so no `IHttpClientFactory`), what is the correct way to read the contents of a file.

I am using the following, and it works. But the compiler is telling me I should not use `WebClient`.

```
public byte[]? GetContent(IBlobService blobService, string blobUrl)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadData(blobUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0) says, "We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."  It's obsolete.

Comment: And the [HttpClient documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) says you don't have to use IHttpClientFactory if you use one HttpClient instance.  But, you'll probably need to change your approach so async can be used because an async Task Main() entry point is required C# 7.1 or later, according to the docs.

Comment: @devlincarnate The problem I face is I have a Blazor (server) app and am using a commercial library for their components. They have an OnLoad event I assign a method to, to load up the content for that component. That event is synchronous. I can't use an await inside it. That's the environment I have to read the file in.

Comment: @DavidThielen You can an async method in a synced context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: @Progman Yes but... I'd rather use an API that is natively synchronous. It's safer. And there should be one for something as basic as this. thanks

Comment: we have methods which are `xxAsync` for HttpClient.... So I'm afraid you might continue to use the WebClient method. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgXV5.png

Answer (score 0):

Since [.NET 5 HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-7.0) exposes a synchronous method called `Send` (the non-async counterpart of `SendAsync`). Then you can use the `ReadAsStream` synchronous method on the `HttpContent` to get the response stream. And finally this can be converted to byte array by utilizing a `MemoryStream`.

```
var client = new HttpClient();        
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, blobUrl);
var response = client.Send(request);

var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStream();       
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream());
responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
return memoryStream.ToArray();
```

This approach could be used only if the to-be-downloaded blob is considered small.

Comment: I'm going to stick with WebClient. It works. thank you for the suggestion though.